# LARAVEL: Button Click Redirects to 404 Instead of Invoking Controller Method

Tags: laravel, routes, controller, http-status-code-404

I've built a WordPress plugin that can be updated by visiting a specific URL (domain.com/wp-json/fetcha/pluginupdate/akismet/akismet.php). That's working well and what it does is it updates the plugin.

Now, I'm trying to add a button in my Laravel application to trigger the same plugin update. But when I press the button, I get a 404 error at localhost/websites/domain.com/update-plugin/litespeed-cache/litespeed-cache.php

Here's the relevant code:

**website_details.blade.php:**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($plugins as $plugin)
        <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
            <td class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">{{ $plugin->plugin_name }}</td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4">{{ $plugin->plugin_version }}</td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4">
                {{ $plugin->plugin_outdated ? 'Outdated' : 'Updated' }}
                @if($plugin->plugin_outdated)
                    **<button onclick="location.href='{{ route('websites.updatePlugin', ['domainName' => $website->domain_name, 'plugin_key' => $plugin->plugin_key]) }}'"** class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2 mr-2">
                        Update Plugin
                    </button>
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**web.php route:**
`Route::get('/websites/{domainName}/update-plugin/{plugin_key}', [WebsiteDetailsController::class, 'updatePlugin'])->name('websites.updatePlugin');`

**WebsiteDetailsController.php:**

```
public function updatePlugin($domainName, $plugin_key)
    {
        Log::debug('ENTRY TO updatePlugin function');
        $encodedPluginSlug = urlencode($plugin_key);
        $url = "https://{$domainName}/wp-json/fetcha/pluginupdate/{$encodedPluginSlug}";
        Log::debug('URL OF PLUGIN THAT WAS BEING UPDATED: ' . $url);
        Log::debug('Generated route URL: ' . route('websites.updatePlugin', ['domainName' => $domainName, 'plugin_key' => $plugin_key]));

        try {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $client->request('GET', $url);
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException $e) {
            Log::error('Guzzle Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        //$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        //$client->request('GET', $url);
    
        return response('Plugin updated successfully!');
    }
```

The first log entry in the updatePlugin function isn't even appearing which gives me an idea that the function is not being called in the first place. Any ideas why this function isn't being called? All my other functions work as expected, just this one's causing issues.

So just to sum it up once again. I press the button Update Plugin -> it redirects me to domain.com/wp-json/fetcha/pluginupdate/akismet/akismet.php that throws 404 error and of course the plugin is not being updated

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if more details are needed.

Clearing all caches, debugging everything with logs - all other functions are called and logs does appear in laravel.log, but not for the function updatePlugin(). I have abused ChatGPT for a few hours :)

The main goal is just that once I press the button Update Plugin it sends a request to domain.com/wp-json/fetcha/pluginupdate/akismet/akismet.php and then it updates the plugin

Comment: Have you checked the network console of the browser to see the details of the call?